# port html5 javascript app that uses SVG to android

Tags: javascript, android, svg

I have a Javascript application that uses SVG and [D3](http://d3js.org/) to render, detect hover events and edit the svg. How could I port this application to android and/or iphone? Phonegap is an option but I'm not sure it would work with SVG and D3 and give me a native apk that could do all that the app is doing.
Thanks :)